# Creating a three-column navigation menu. Having trouble with valid structuring that allows independent scrolling

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, css

As the title says, I am working on a three-level column navigation menu, similar to the column view for OS X's Finder. My first approach was essentially a minimal version of [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-column-navigation/) (working demo files [here](http://jquery-column-navigation.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=40001000&name=column-navigation.zip&token=Dx1AESbuxoxqW6ATWqjc1i80nlI%3A1326146331265)). The problem with that is that s are not allowed as children of s. Everything works fine, but it won't validate. If you take out the s, the individual columns won't scroll (even if you change line 245 in query-columnnav-1.0.js to look for ).

The only other example of this I have found is on Apple's [dashboard widgets](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/) site, but it looks like they just have three arbitrary s which they fill with content depending on what is clicked, which doesn't seem to be the best way to go about it.

I've haven't used custom scrollbars before, but I was thinking that there might be one out there that would allow the  to scroll via javascript positioning or something.

Good to note: The site is for students at my university, and after having the site up for one semester, we had two hits from IE (8.0 and 9.0), and all the rest were from recent browsers. Because of this, we can allow CSS3 and HTML5, as long as they have graceful fallbacks. If a browsers fails horrendously, we'll just tell them to upgrade, and it won't be a big loss for us.

**tl;dr:** I need ideas on how to structure a column navigation so each column can scroll independently. Previous attempts don't validate. Don't work about IE or older browsers. Thanks!

*Edit:* I am looking at jScrollPane right now. This might be what I want. Still looking for advice, though.

*Edit2:* I didn't clarify this, the HTML is generated in this fashion:

```
<ul class="all departments">
    <li class="first department">
        <ul class="all courses in department">
            <li class="first course">
                <ul class="all sections on course">
                  <li class="first section"></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you can just use some really simple CSS to make it work. A container div with three smaller divs inside it that are floated left and forced to scroll. Like so:

```
div.columncont
{
 height: 500px;
 width: 600px;
}
div.column
{
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Just adjust the sizes for what fits into what you are trying to do. I made an example of [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZssG/)

Also, I don't have commenting permissions so this is my only way of letting you know that your link to the jquery-column-navigation is broken.

Comment: I'm sorry but that comment makes no sense. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Lost the ability to edit my comment halfway through. HEre you go:

I could do it that way, I guess I didn't make this clear, though. The data I am working with is the course listings. First level is the department, then the course, then the sections. We currently generate the HTML in the manner of: *I put it up top because the whitespace was removed.*